How to make TS check type any, when working with useState (React)?
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export type TTOrigin = {
  name: 'Name1' | 'Name2'
  url: string
}

export function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<TTOrigin[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }, [])

  return <h1>App</h1>
}

JSON has type any. But TS allows to put it in setData. Although in useState the type TTOrigin is specified


not sure what you mean but if you want to define the type of json, just use setData(json as TTOrigin[]) .

Your question contradicts itself. Using any means that you lose all type checks. any is assignable to anything and can be assigned anything.

@Behemoth Can we do a check for any? When the function accepts an exact type, not accept any?

The rule in Typescript is that no type checks are done on code that involves a variable of type any.
It basically means that for all such code parts, Typescript will behave as JavaScript and the developer is responsible again for doing type checks (is this really an array / string / number), content checks (is this string really only "Y" or "N"), property name checks and what not.
The example code below runs and will show that the string variable a can suddenly contain a number 3:
let a: string = "x"
let b: any = 3
a = b;
console.log(a)
console.log(typeof a)

TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/FAGwpgLgBAhgXFAzhATgSwHYHMoF4oBEAHgaJFAEYIwYCeeUAzMDAxQNzADGA9hoj3AA6EDywAKGAEpufAcNESItAA5geAM1gzgwIA

Yes, I understand. But I didn't declare the any type for json. That means TS is missing the point. And I could potentially catch an error here.

By having .then((json) => setData(json)), the type for json is implicitly any so the setData() call is compiled without type checks. You could change it to .then((json: TTOrigin[]) => setData(json)) but that only influences your code, the then itself uses any so it doesn't see or care what you put there or not.

any is a special type in TypeScript because it is assignable to anything and can be assigned to anything. Simply put, any turns off type checks. That's why you can pass json to setData() without compiler error.

Regarding "Can we do a check for any?".
Yes, you can using a conditional type. Since any will allow any assignment you can check if two unassignable values will be assignable when intersected with any. See jcalz' great answer on the question Typescript check for the 'any' type. The following will raise a compiler error if json is of type any by returning unknown.
setData(json as (0 extends (1 & typeof json) ? unknown : typeof json)

Many people consider fetch unsafe because it returns Promise<any>. So you might also consider overriding the global definition with interface declaration merging.
declare global {
  interface Body {
    json(): Promise<unknown>;
  }
}

With the above declaration added, it will require you to assert the json type before assigning it.
setData(json as TTOrigin[])


Typescript is compile-time type-checking... it's all just Javascript at runtime when the code is actually executed. Even if json was specifically typed and correct for compilation, it could be something else at runtime, whatever that "https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/" endpoint spits back to the client.
The code you have is fine as far as Typescript is concerned, but if you wanted to you could cast/type json to the expected TTOriginp[] type.
Examples:
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/")
    .then((res) => res.json() as unknown as TTOrigin[])
    .then((json) => setData(json))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json: TTOrigin[]) => setData(json))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => setData(json as TTOrigin[]))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}, []);


In addition to the other answers that have been given (which should be understood; there is no runtime type checking), I'm going to point you at schema validators. Zod is my personal favorite, but there are plenty like Yup, Joi, and io-ts that all do the same thing, as well.
Because your data is read over the network at runtime, types have been fully erased, and there is no chance for the data to be checked against your types for compliance. any is the correct type for the result of parsing a string with JSON.parse, because at compile time, there is no way to know what the output of that will be! You can cast the result to your type, but all you're doing there is saying "for the purposes of compilation, assume that this data structure has this shape"; there is no runtime guarantee that it actually does, which can lead to bugs (for example, if the remote endpoint changed the shape of the payload returned).
The point of a schema validator is to ensure that data received at runtime conforms to a defined schema, so that you can operate on it with confidence that the data as typed in your code is the data that you'll be operating on.
Zod gives you a way to write runtime validators which also give you typescript types. From the example:
const User = z.object({
  username: z.string(),
});

const parsedUser = User.parse(JSON.parse(remotelyLoadedDocument)));

// extract the inferred type
type User = z.infer<typeof User>;

When this code runs, it will ensure that the data parsed from JSON.parse(remotelyLoadedDocument) does actually conform to the User schema you declared, and at compile time, the type of parsedUser will be {username: string}, which lets you consume it in your code in a safely-typed manner.
